# Finding the intervals of increase and decrease of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I have this question here:

> Find the intervals of increase and decrease of the function
>
> $$f(x)=2\cos(x)+2\sin(x)+\ln|\cos(x)|$$
>
> for $0\leq x\leq 2\pi$.

Simple enough. I take the derivative and I get:

$$f'(x)=-2\sin(x)+2\cos(x)-\tan(x)$$

which I believe is correct. I can then rewrite this as:

$$f'(x)=\frac{-2\sin(x)\cos(x)+2\cos^2(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$

So for the denominator, the critical points occur at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$. However, how do I solve for $x$ in the numerator? I don't think I can do it algebraically and I need to use a numerical approach however, I am not sure. Can anyone advice? Thanks!

Comment: WolframAlpha is able to find the roots of the numerator, see [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve++-2*sin%28x%29*cos%28x%29+%2B+2*%28cos%28x%29%29%5E2-sin%28x%29%3D0)

Comment: How is this function defined when $x = \frac \pi 2$ and then $\cos x = 0$?

Comment: I'm not saying it's defined. I'm saying those are critical points which occur when the derivative is $0$ or undefined.